# Inner produt space

Tags: real-analysis

Let 
‎‎‏‎$ ‎‎X=C[-1,1]‎$‎‎
be inner product space 
with definition 
‎‎$‎\langle f,g‎‎ ‎\rangle ‎=‎\int‎‎^1_{-1}{f ‎‎\bar{g}‎} ‎dt ‎‎$.‎‎
Suppose
‎$$ ‎M= ‎‎\lbrace{ f‎  \in ‎X: ‎f(t)=0 ,‎ ( ‎‎-1 \leq‎ t ‎‎\leq ‎0)‎‎\rbrace}. ‎$$‎‎
Then which of the following options is correct?
‎$‎‎ ‎M= ‎M^{‎\perp‎\perp} ‎‎$
‎$$ M‎ ‎‎\bigoplus ‎M^{‎\perp}=X$$
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this is strange, because $1$ is not a vector subspace of $C[-1,1]$, and further it is well known that $C[-1,1]$ is not complete (whose completion is well-known to be $L^{2}[-1,1]$). But forgetting all these notational issue for now, assume $1-M$ means $1-f,f\in M$. Then you want to show $$\int (1-f_{1})\overline{g}=0,\forall g, \int f\overline{g}=0,\forall f,f_{1}\in M$$

It is clear that for $g\in M^{\perp}$, $g$ can only have nonzero value at $t$. But since $g$ is continuous, if $g$ is positive at $t$ it must be positive near $t$. Hence $g$ will not be orthogonal to all $f$ in $M$. Therefore $M^{\perp}$ has to be $0$. Since $\langle 1-M,0\rangle$ is certainly $0$, we have $1-M\subset {M^{\perp}}^{\perp}$. The other direction is clearly wrong, since $0^{\perp}=C[-1,1]$ itself.

I won't bother to solve the second problem as it looks as well not appropriately defined.

Comment: I encourage you to solve by yourself for this level of problems.